# Symfony 3.0: How I will know when an Entry Successfully Inserted?

Tags: php, doctrine, symfony

I have made on my Symfony 3.0 project a User Entity:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;


/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="users")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Entity\UserRepository")
 */
class Users
{
  /**
   * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=60)
   * @ORM\Id
   * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="CUSTOM")
   * @ORM\CustomIdGenerator(class="AppBundle\Doctrine\AutoIdGenerate")
   */
  private $id;

  /**
   * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=15)
   */
  private $username;

  /**
   * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=30)
   */
  private $password;

  /**
   * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=60)
   * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="CUSTOM")
   * @ORM\CustomIdGenerator(class="AppBundle\Doctrine\AutoIdGenerate")
   */
  private $token;

  /**
   * @ORM\Column(type="boolean")
   */
  private $activated;

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set username
     *
     * @param string $username
     *
     * @return Users
     */
    public function setUsername($username)
    {
        $this->username = strip_tags($username);

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get username
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getUsername()
    {
        return $this->username;
    }

    /**
     * Set password
     *
     * @param string $password
     *
     * @return Users
     */
    public function setPassword($password)
    {
      $options = ['cost' => 42];
      $this->password = password_hash ($password,CRYPT_BLOWFISH,$options);

      return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get password
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getPassword()
    {
        return $this->password;
    }

    /**
     * Set token
     *
     * @param string $token
     *
     * @return Users
     */
    public function setToken($token)
    {
        $this->token = $token;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get token
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getToken()
    {
        return $this->token;
    }

    /**
     * Set activated
     *
     * @param boolean $activated
     *
     * @return Users
     */
    public function setActivated($activated)
    {
        $this->activated = $activated;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get activated
     *
     * @return boolean
     */
    public function getActivated()
    {
        return $this->activated;
    }

}
```

And a Repository that Iplements My logic:

```
<?php
namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use AppBundle\Entity\Product;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;

class UserRepository extends EntityRepository
{
  public function register($username,$password,$email)
  {
    //A Generic return Object
    $status=array('status'=>'true','data'=>"");

    if(empty($username))
    {
      $status['status']=-1;
      $status['data']='Username not given';
      return $status;
    }

    if(empty($password))
    {
      $status['status']=-1;
      $status['data']='Password not given';
      return $status;
    }

    if(empty($email))
    {
      $status['status']=-1;
      $status['data']='Email not given';
      return $status;
    }


    $user=new User();
    $user->setUsername($username)->setPassword($password);

    $em=$this->getEntityManager();

    $em->persist($user);
    $em->flush();

    return $status;
  }

}
```

What I wanna know is when an Entry Sucessfully Inserted to send the email to verify the registration. How I will know That the User Has Sucessfully Inserted In the DB; Also How I will take any Sort of AutoGenerated  Fields such as id and token in order to verify the mail address.

I Found that In order to Use Email I can Use the Swiftmailer so the Question
Is NOT hoiw to send  an Email, but how I will know that the user successfully inserted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your entry is correctly inserted, you'll not have any error.
Otherwise, you'll have one (unless you have a mistake that is not coming from the insertion).

To catch a possible error, you can do this :

```
// ...
$em->persist($user);
try {
    $em->flush();
     // Success 
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    $result['data'] = $e->getMessage(); // The exact message of the exception thrown during INSERT
    // Error
}
```

Otherwise, you can consider the entry has been stored.

For the auto-generated fields, they are immediately available through getters after calling `$em->flush()`.

Comment: @DimitrosDesyllas Why this unaccept ? Is your problem unsolved ?

Answer (score 1):

You can register Event Listener for Doctrine `postFlush` event.

Example listener:

```
<?php
use Doctrine\ORM\Event\PostFlushEventArgs;

class PostFlushExampleListener
{
    public function postFlush(PostFlushEventArgs $args)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Service registration in Symfony:

```
services:
    my.listener:
        class: PostFlushExampleListener
        tags:
            - { name: doctrine.event_listener, event: postFlush }
```

Symfony documentation: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/event_listeners_subscribers.html

Doctrine documentation: http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/events.html#listening-and-subscribing-to-lifecycle-events

You should have all autogenerated fields available just after calling `flush` action there where you call it. Doctrine events are non mandatory in your case. I would just assume that after flush i will have all needed data and data will be set in database.